# How to add multiple drop-down filter in the HTML table made by fetching JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, filter

I Have made an HTML Table which fetches the data from Google sheet via JSON.

I need to put drop-down filters on the table based on multiple data in different columns. Also is it possible to put a number range filter for a particular column (column G & H) and Time range Filter for Column C?

I am stuck on it and can not find any working code for the above. Any reference would also helpful.
Thanks!

***HTML Code***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Notice Board</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" >
<!--    Here goes the table -->
    <h1 class="text-center">Notice Board</h1>
    <div id="data">
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/newscript.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
 // JS starts here

url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sLlp6FMIRYLbcyq_59x_m2Ly4mm4ZilWL0EHmjsSA8s/1/public/values?alt=json';

function Get(url){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",url,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}

var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get(url)); 
var feed_length = json_obj.feed.entry.length; 


for (value = 0; value < feed_length; value++) { 
    var data_array = json_obj.feed.entry[value];
    var notice = data_array['gsx$notice']['$t'];
    var date = data_array['gsx$date']['$t'];
    var time= data_array['gsx$time']['$t'];
    var city = data_array['gsx$city']['$t'];
    var country = data_array['gsx$country']['$t'];
    var status = data_array['gsx$status']['$t'];
    var pmdnumber = data_array['gsx$pmdnumber']['$t'];
    var cknnumber= data_array['gsx$cknnumber']['$t'];


    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML+= ('<div class="panel-default panel-body card">'+ 
     '<div class="column1">'+
     '<p><span class="label label-warning">'+notice+'</span></p>'+
     '<p><span class="label label-warning label-big">'+city+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+country+'</span></p>'+ 
     '</div>'+

     '<div class="column2">'+
     '<p><span class="label label-warning label-big">'+date+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+time+'</span></p>'+
     '</div>'+

     '<div class="column3">'+
     '<p><span class="label label-warning">'+pmdnumber+'</span></p>'+
     '<p><span class="label label-warning">'+cknnumber+'</p>'+
     '</div>'+

     '<div class="column4">'+
     '<p class="label label-success label-big">'+status+'</p>'+ '</div>' +

     '</div>' 
     );
}
```

I think the JSON can be filtered out before it runs inside the loop.

***Google Spreadsheet Link***
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sLlp6FMIRYLbcyq_59x_m2Ly4mm4ZilWL0EHmjsSA8s/edit?usp=sharing

***Spreadsheet JSON Link***
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1sLlp6FMIRYLbcyq_59x_m2Ly4mm4ZilWL0EHmjsSA8s/1/public/values?alt=json